# CustomControl with shapes

Tags: c#, custom-controls, microsoft-metro

I would like to create a custom control in order to display a pie chart.
I have a PieSlice class (which I got from the WinRT toolkit project) :

```
public class PieSlice : Path
{
    #region StartAngle
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "StartAngle",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(PieSlice),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                0d,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnStartAngleChanged)));

    public double StartAngle
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(StartAngleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StartAngleProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnStartAngleChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = (PieSlice)sender;
        var oldStartAngle = (double)e.OldValue;
        var newStartAngle = (double)e.NewValue;
        target.OnStartAngleChanged(oldStartAngle, newStartAngle);
    }

    private void OnStartAngleChanged(double oldStartAngle, double newStartAngle)
    {
        UpdatePath();
    }
    #endregion

    #region EndAngle
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EndAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "EndAngle",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(PieSlice),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                0d,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnEndAngleChanged)));

    public double EndAngle
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(EndAngleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EndAngleProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnEndAngleChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = (PieSlice)sender;
        var oldEndAngle = (double)e.OldValue;
        var newEndAngle = (double)e.NewValue;
        target.OnEndAngleChanged(oldEndAngle, newEndAngle);
    }

    private void OnEndAngleChanged(double oldEndAngle, double newEndAngle)
    {
        UpdatePath();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Radius
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Radius",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(PieSlice),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                0d,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnRadiusChanged)));

    public double Radius
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnRadiusChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = (PieSlice)sender;
        var oldRadius = (double)e.OldValue;
        var newRadius = (double)e.NewValue;
        target.OnRadiusChanged(oldRadius, newRadius);
    }

    private void OnRadiusChanged(double oldRadius, double newRadius)
    {
        this.Width = this.Height = 2 * Radius;
        UpdatePath();
    }
    #endregion

    private void UpdatePath()
    {
        var pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        var pathFigure = new PathFigure();
        pathFigure.StartPoint = new Point(Radius, Radius);
        pathFigure.IsClosed = true;

        // Starting Point
        var lineSegment = 
            new LineSegment 
            {
                Point = new Point(
                    Radius + Math.Sin(StartAngle * Math.PI / 180) * Radius,
                    Radius - Math.Cos(StartAngle * Math.PI / 180) * Radius)
            };

        // Arc
        var arcSegment = new ArcSegment();
        arcSegment.IsLargeArc = (EndAngle - StartAngle) >= 180.0;
        arcSegment.Point =
            new Point(
                    Radius + Math.Sin(EndAngle * Math.PI / 180) * Radius,
                    Radius - Math.Cos(EndAngle * Math.PI / 180) * Radius);
        arcSegment.Size = new Size(Radius, Radius);
        arcSegment.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Clockwise;
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(lineSegment);
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(arcSegment);
        pathGeometry.Figures.Add(pathFigure);
        this.Data = pathGeometry;
        this.InvalidateArrange();
    }
}
```

And now I am trying to create a control which can contains multiple pie slices

```
public class Pie : Control
{
    #region Items Source
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ItemsSource",
            typeof(IEnumerable),
            typeof(Pie),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                null,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourceChanged)));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = (Pie)sender;
        var oldItemsSource = (IEnumerable)e.OldValue;
        var newItemsSource = (IEnumerable)e.NewValue;
        target.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldItemsSource, newItemsSource);
    }

    private void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldItemsSource, IEnumerable newItemsSource)
    {
        UpdatePieSlices();
    }
    #endregion

    public Pie()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Pie);
    }

    private void UpdatePieSlices()
    {
        double startAngle = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> item in ItemsSource)
        {
            PieSlice slice = new PieSlice() 
            { 
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), 
                Radius = 100, StartAngle = startAngle, 
                EndAngle = (item.Value / 100.0) * 360 
            };
            startAngle = (item.Value / 100.0) * 360;
        }
    }
}
```

The ItemsSource is a collection of `KeyValuePair<string, int>` which represents the name of the slice and the percentage. I would like to display the slices but I have no idea how...

EDIT :

I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
<Style TargetType="control:Pie">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="control:Pie">
                    <Border
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                        <ItemsControl
                            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                            AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource}">

                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <Grid></Grid>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display is the province of the control's default look, defined in XAML.

What I'd probably do is get the control to expose a `DependencyProperty` which is a collection of objects representing the slices. Each object would contain enough information to correctly display the slice it corresponds to, which your control's code would have to calculate when `ItemsSource` changes.

Then in the XAML, bind that to an `ItemsControl` which has a `DataTemplate` which binds the slice description objects to actual `PieSlice` objects, and an `ItemsPanelTemplate` which is probably just a `Grid` or a `Canvas` to allow the segments to pile up around each other.

What you're doing is creating the actual `PieSlice` objects, which is okay, but they have to be displayed differently - you could bind a collection of them to an `ItemsControl` which uses `ContentControl` as its `ItemTemplate`, binding `Content` to each `PieSlice`.

```
<DataTemplate><ContentControl Content="{Binding}" /></DataTemplate>
```

Information about creating custom controls for WPF and Silverlight will serve you well here, as the underlying ideas and much of the technology are the same in WinRT.

Comment: Could you provide more details ? I have edited my post with xaml but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Peekyou can you please edit your question with your final working solution? Thanks.